# Rewriting a Python module only if it gets imported

Tags: python, python-import, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm writing a library that uses abstract syntax trees to rewrite parts of a
module. Once it's rewritten, I put it in `sys.modules` so other modules can
call it. However, the timing is important, and I can't just run the rewritten module
at the start. I want it to run when it gets imported by another module, and not
before.

I had solved this by writing an [importer](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-importer), but that used the `imp` module to
create a new module object for my rewritten code. That `imp` module is now
deprecated, and the replacement doesn't seem to let me create and execute a
new module. It just lets me find the source file, and create a spec object
pointing to that.

If I can't use the `imp` module anymore, How can I create a new module with the
rewritten code?

As a trivial example, I have a module that just prints out a couple of messages:

```
# my_module.py
print('This is in my_module.py.')

def do_something():
    print('Doing something.')
```

My tracer has options for whether or not to import my_module.py and whether or
not to rewrite it with an extra `print()` message.

```
# tracer.py
import builtins
import imp
import sys
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from ast import NodeTransformer, Expr, Call, Name, Load, Str, parse, fix_missing_locations
from pathlib import Path


def main():
    print('Starting.')
    args = parse_args()

    if args.traced:
        sys.meta_path.insert(0, TracedModuleImporter('my_module'))
        print('Set up tracing.')

    if args.imported:
        from my_module import do_something
        do_something()

    print('Done.')


class TracedModuleImporter(object):
    PSEUDO_FILENAME = '<traced>'

    def __init__(self, fullname):
        self.fullname = fullname
        source = Path(fullname + '.py').read_text()
        tree = parse(source, self.PSEUDO_FILENAME)
        new_tree = Tracer().visit(tree)
        fix_missing_locations(new_tree)
        self.code = compile(new_tree, self.PSEUDO_FILENAME, 'exec')

    def find_module(self, fullname, path=None):
        if fullname != self.fullname:
            return None
        return self

    def load_module(self, fullname):
        new_mod = imp.new_module(fullname)
        sys.modules[fullname] = new_mod
        new_mod.__builtins__ = builtins
        new_mod.__file__ = self.PSEUDO_FILENAME
        new_mod.__package__ = None

        exec(self.code, new_mod.__dict__)
        return new_mod


class Tracer(NodeTransformer):
    def visit_Module(self, node):
        new_node = self.generic_visit(node)
        new_node.body.append(Expr(value=Call(func=Name(id='print', ctx=Load()),
                                             args=[Str(s='Traced')],
                                             keywords=[])))
        return new_node


def parse_args():
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--imported', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('--traced', action='store_true')
    return parser.parse_args()


main()
```

When I call it, you can see the messages:

```
$ python tracer.py
Starting.
Done.
$ python tracer.py --imported
Starting.
This is in my_module.py.
Doing something.
Done.
$ python tracer.py --imported --traced
Starting.
Set up tracing.
This is in my_module.py.
Traced
Doing something.
Done.
$ python tracer.py --traced
Starting.
Set up tracing.
Done.
```

That all works fine with Python 3.6, but Python 3.7 complains about the `imp` module:

```
$ python tracer.py
tracer.py:100: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  import imp
Starting.
Done.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I misunderstood the importer protocol. You can override the  part that executes the module, and leave the part that creates the new module unchanged. Here's my example, rewritten to use the newer importer protocol with `find_spec()` and `execute_module()` instead of `find_module()` and `load_module()`.

```
import sys
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from ast import NodeTransformer, Expr, Call, Name, Load, Str, parse, fix_missing_locations
from importlib.abc import MetaPathFinder, Loader
from importlib.machinery import ModuleSpec
from pathlib import Path


def main():
    print('Starting.')
    args = parse_args()

    if args.traced:
        sys.meta_path.insert(0, TracedModuleImporter('my_module'))
        print('Set up tracing.')

    if args.imported:
        from my_module import do_something
        do_something()

    print('Done.')


class TracedModuleImporter(MetaPathFinder, Loader):
    PSEUDO_FILENAME = '<traced>'

    def __init__(self, fullname):
        self.fullname = fullname
        source = Path(fullname + '.py').read_text()
        tree = parse(source, self.PSEUDO_FILENAME)
        new_tree = Tracer().visit(tree)
        fix_missing_locations(new_tree)
        self.code = compile(new_tree, self.PSEUDO_FILENAME, 'exec')

    def find_spec(self, fullname, path, target=None):
        if fullname != self.fullname:
            return None
        return ModuleSpec(fullname, self)

    def exec_module(self, module):
        module.__file__ = self.PSEUDO_FILENAME
        exec(self.code, module.__dict__)


class Tracer(NodeTransformer):
    def visit_Module(self, node):
        new_node = self.generic_visit(node)
        new_node.body.append(Expr(value=Call(func=Name(id='print', ctx=Load()),
                                             args=[Str(s='Traced')],
                                             keywords=[])))
        return new_node


def parse_args():
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--imported', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('--traced', action='store_true')
    return parser.parse_args()


main()
```

The output from that is exactly the same as the old version, but the deprecation warning is gone.